# Set date in a date field

Tags: windows, user-interface, testing, autoit

I am trying to set the date in a date picker field in a Windows environment (shown in attached images). It's not [an AutoIt date control](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlCreateDate.htm) (I did not create this field). I used the following code:

```
; enter from date

$sFromDate  = "09/01/2017"
ControlFocus($hWnd, "", "WindowsForms10.SysDateTimePick32.app.01")
ControlSetText($hWnd, "", "WindowsForms10.SysDateTimePick32.app.01", $sFromDate )
```

The AutoIt Window Information Tool shows info about the control but not the items (month/day/year) inside it. I am looking for any tool to set the date, not necessarily AutoIt.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See description and example of _GUICtrlDTP_SetSystemTime
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlDTP_SetSystemTime.htm

Try to use this example:

```
#include <GuiDateTimePicker.au3>

Local $a_Date[7] = [False, @YEAR, 8, 19, 21, 57, 34]

$hDTP = ControlGetHandle("Set_Window_Title_Here", "", "WindowsForms10.SysDateTimePick32.app.01")
_GUICtrlDTP_SetSystemTime($hDTP, $a_Date)
```